# Connecting to MySQL via SSH and private key

Tags: linux

I am trying to connect to MySQL databases server remotely via ssh using key. I enable port 3306 in server and allows tcp in firewall and bind address. I used this command in SSH:

```
ssh -i <key> serveruser@ipadd -L 3306:<MySQL_IP>:3306 -N
```

Am using Fedora Linux in my laptop and server is CentOS.

Comment: Your command is confusing - do you actually have `that I bind` in the console command?

Comment: ssh -i <key> server domain.com -L 3306:MySQL user ip:3306  -N      .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$ ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 user@your-remote-server.com
```

The option `-L` will do a local port forwarding from port `3307` (your computer)
to port `3306` in `localhost` (the remote server), then you could connect by doing

```
$ mysql -h localhost -P 3307
```

The idea of using `3307` instead of `3306` is just in case you have a local mysql already up and running on default port `3306`